# How to create two models with required ForeignKey fields to eachother?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, both of them with a ForeignKey field to eachother.

```py
from django.db import models


class County(models.Model):
    capital = models.ForeignKey("Municipality", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="capital_of")


class Municipality(models.Model):
    county = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="municipalities")
```

With these models, I'm unable to create nor an instance of County or Municipality. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: ForeignKey relationships are Many-to-one so this isn't possible. Look into One-to-One fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: to add, if a model has a foreignkey then it MUST have an object that it is linked to through the key. if you have two models with foreignkeys to eachother you can never create one cause they need the other to already exist

Comment: Is this solvable using the OneToOneField instead?

Comment: I mean, how should then my models look like? A county needs a capital, and a municipality is always situated in a county. 